# PHP - Directory's stat['mtime'] not updating when in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, stat

Here's my code:

```
while (true) {
  $stat = stat('/path/to/dir/');
  echo $stat['mtime'].PHP_EOL;
  sleep(1);
}
```

If I run this in terminal and then create a new file in the directory the `mtime` doesn't change. If I stop the script, and start it again the correct `mtime` is output. Why is `stat` not updating?

Comment: [clearstatcache()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).... the [PHP Docs for stat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) do tell you about this

Comment: The same thing from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25833630/3885509) question also goes for your question.